# Is there a dust-free alternative to gravel for an indoor Petanque Court?

Tags: materials, stone, gravel

We are considering constructing a [Pétanque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9tanque) court in our office.

The typical finished playing surface is sand, gravel, small pebbles or sometimes shell.

We need a dust-free material so that when people step in and out of the court, they don't track dust around the office.

The material will be challenged by metal boules that are lobbed around the surface as part of the game, and players walking around the surface.

What are some alternative materials (or coated materials) that have similar properties to sand or gravel, but that are dust-free?

Comment: Pure sand is dust free. It is just silicone particles. Dusty sand is sand with smaller particles of contamination. Using artificial filler will also gather dust- but has better properties for electrolysing and thus dust will try to bind to it. Still wont stop dust from spreading if it the filler gets invigorated about. Using coarse sand with a dust grid is a much better solution. Coarse sand 2-4mm will not stick to shoes and when invigorated dust particles will be driven downwards through a 0.5mm grid where a (vacuum system)or(electrolysis system) can arrest the unwanted dust.

Comment: Is surrounding the court with some type of mat (where players can wipe there feet), and option?

Answer (score 5):

If this is an interior installation then no powder/gravel based playing surface will be "dust free" as the impact of the balls will create dust.  Reading up on the game, it does say that it can be played on grass.

Based on that, for an indoor game, I'd go with hard rubberized flooring (such as used in gymnasiums) topped with interior AstroTurf of a short cut.

Comment: Thanks. I had imagined pebbles coated with some sort of 'non-dust gathering' material that would have been dust free. But considering a non-traditional surface like astroturf is definitely a creative solution. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This may be heresy, but what about using [soft indoor pétanque balls](https://web.archive.org/web/20111230132500/http://petanque-america.com:80/indoorpetanque.html) that should allow you to play the game on a carpet without having to deal with gravel and dust?
[image: indoor petanque balls]

Comment: Soft indoor balls may also be safer for our glass doors. Thanks.